# Keras save both protobuffer and weights in training callback with custom filenames

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to write a callback for my model fit procedure that if after an Epoch ends, the model improved, saves me the weights **and** the model as a protobuffer.
Preferably to something like `./tmp/weights.hdf5` and `./tmp/model.pb`. I use two callbacks for that (mnist example below, I'm using TF 2.6.0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def create_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  ])

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              steps_per_execution=10)

callback_weights = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="./tmp/weights.hdf5", save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)

callback_model = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="./tmp/", save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=True)

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          epochs=2,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[callback_weights, callback_model])
```

And `ls tmp` gives:

`assets  keras_metadata.pb  saved_model.pb  variables  weights.hdf5`

My questions:

- Do I have to use two callbacks for this or can this be done in one callback?
- How do I control the name of the protobuffer file? Specifying the filename when `save_weights_only=True` works, but when I do that with `save_weights_only=False` it creates a directory from the `filepath` argument.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your above specific question,

(1). We do not have to use two callbacks for this (saving model or weight). It can be done with one callback.
(2). When we set `save_weights_only=False`, it means that the program will save the whole model with its current state (or weight). To get a more clear understanding, please see below

```
# it'll save only weight 
callback_weights = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="weights.h5", 
    save_weights_only=True,  
    save_best_only=True)

# it'll save model config + weight = entire trained model 
callback_weights_model = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="model.h5", 
    save_weights_only=False, # entire model (config + weight)
    save_best_only=True)

# it'll also save model config + weight = entire trained model 
callback_model = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="./tmp/", 
    save_weights_only=False, # entire model (config + weight)
    save_best_only=True)
```

Here, `callback_weights_model` and `callback_model` will do the same job with different output formats. But `callback_weights` will only save the current state or trained weight file. So, if we use them in the training time as follows:

```
model.fit(...
          callbacks=[callback_weights, 
                     callback_model, 
                     callback_weights_model])
```

then we will have the following files.

```
tmp/ [asset, variable, .pb]
model.h5
weight.h5
```

Let's check

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./tmp/')
assert np.allclose(model.predict(x_test), loaded_model.predict(x_test))

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/model.h5')
assert np.allclose(model.predict(x_test), loaded_model.predict(x_test))

#  ValueError: No model config found in the file at /content/weights.h5.
# loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/weights.h5') 

loaded_model = create_model()
loaded_model.load_weights('/content/weights.h5')
assert np.allclose(model.predict(x_test), loaded_model.predict(x_test))
```

So, if we need to save the entire model, we may pick the `callback_weights_model` or the `callback_model` callback above. Otherwise, if we only need to save the weight file, we can use `callback_weights`.

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ok, with `callback_weights_model` I get the model including the weights. But is it not possible to export the protobuffer (.pb) and the model weights (.h5) in one callback?

Comment: afaik, in one callback we can't use .pb or .h5 at the same time. actually, that somewhat doesn't make any sense. because, in pb, you will get model_config + model_weight. So, if it's possible to save pb and h5 in one callback, it will save model weight two times in that sense.

Comment: Or, you can write a custom callback and save the pb and h5 files manually.

Comment: Yes, I understand the redundancy in it... I guess I will find a way to only deal with the saved weights, since the model architecture is fixed... Thanks!